# The Masstransit doesn't want to consume faults messages

Tags: .net, masstransit

I am trying to write an error message handler according to the documentation:
https://masstransit-project.com/usage/exceptions.html#faults
[image]

But the message falls into the queue with the prefix _error and that's it. Nothing else is happening. Tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My consumers:

```cs
public class CustomerCreatedEventConsumer : 
    IConsumer<CustomerCreatedArgs>
{

    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<CustomerCreatedArgs> context)
    {
        throw new Exception("TEST EXCEPTION!!!!");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}


public class DashboardFaultConsumer :
    IConsumer<Fault<CustomerCreatedArgs>>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Fault<CustomerCreatedArgs>> context)
    {
        /// !!!
        ///  This part of the code should work out, but it does not work out
        /// !!!
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

My configuration:

```
public static class ConfigureServicesMassTransit
{
    public static void ConfigureMassTransitServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var massTransitSection = configuration.GetSection("MassTransit");
        var url = massTransitSection.GetValue<string>("Url");
        var host = massTransitSection.GetValue<string>("Host");
        var userName = massTransitSection.GetValue<string>("UserName");
        var password = massTransitSection.GetValue<string>("Password");

        if (massTransitSection == null || url == null || host == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Section 'MassTransit' configuration settings are not found in appsettings.json");
        }

        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            AddConsumers(x);
            x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
            {

                cfg.Host($"{url}", configurator =>
                {
                    configurator.Username(userName);
                    configurator.Password(password);
                });

                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
            });
        });
    }

    private static void AddConsumers(IServiceCollectionBusConfigurator x)
    {
        x.AddConsumer<CustomerCreatedEventConsumer>();
        x.AddConsumer<DashboardFaultConsumer>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the logs, see what's happening. Make sure your message type is `public`.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson In the logs I see a fail level message with the text `Mass Transit.ReceiveTransport[0] R-FAULT etc..` and the message type I have is `public`

Comment: If you don't see it publishing the fault in the logs, well, not sure what else to tell you. The logs usually reveal all.